# How do i re use this class in all my mxml components

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

Please i am new to Flex and Actionscript 3, but i know its an OOP language, I'm coming from a Java Background. I have a class that helps me check if the user of my AIR app has an internet connection it works well when included directly in my mxml class. Wanted to know if its possible to insert it in an actionscript class and reuse it in any mxml component class i wish to.

EDIT

```
package components
{
    import air.net.URLMonitor;

    import flash.events.StatusEvent;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class NetworkChecker
    {
        private var monitor:URLMonitor;
        private var myURL = new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com");

        public function NetworkChecker()
        {
            myURL.method = "HEAD";
            monitor = new URLMonitor(myURL);
            monitor.start();
            monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, on_Connection);
        }
        public function on_Connection(event:StatusEvent):void
        {
            if(event.target.available == true)
            {
                trace("Internet Connection is available");
            }
            else
            {
                trace("No internet Connection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please how do i call this code from an mxml component? it works well when i include it directly in the fx:Script tag. I need to know if event.target.available is true of false in my mxml component...

Comment: How do you use it in your MXML Class?  Why doesn't the same exact approach work in an ActionScript class?

Comment: just create the instance of this class and store the reference to it to prevent garbage collection: _private var monitor:NetworkCheckerr; monitor = new NetworkCheckerr()_

Comment: Thanks, but in my mxml i need to know if event.target.available is true or false. How do i do that?

Comment: The same way you do it in the code you already posted.

Comment: A code snippet would really help

Comment: MXML Classes are nearly always Views, which shouldn't care about this sort of thing. Your Class doesn't actually expose anything that would make it useful to use from the outside, so it seems sort of pointless to try to use it, much less reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
    public function on_Connection(event:StatusEvent):boolean
    {
        if(event.target.available == true)
        {
            trace("Internet Connection is available");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            trace("No internet Connection");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

or better still:

```
    public function on_Connection(event:StatusEvent):boolean
    {
        return event.target.available;
    }
```

**NOTE:** this assumes that `event.target.available` is defined...

Answer (score 0):

Add public proprerty to NetworkChecker class

```
[Bindable]
public var available:Boolean = false;
```

then

```
public function on_Connection(event:StatusEvent):void
        {           
           this.available = event.target.available;
        }
```

mxml

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <components:NetworkChecker id="checker"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button label="Button" enabled="{checker.available}"/>
```

and more:
You should add eventListener before monitor start in constructor function